# Synchronizing angular interceptor objects

Tags: angular

I created interceptor that
1) Show error toast on catchError();
2) using tap() if method was not GET shows toast telling that data was successfully saved.

The problem is, sometimes there are multiple methods called in a short span and I want to debounce showing success toast.

I'm not sure what is the best way to handle this using angular, if I understand correctly each request creates new interceptor. I tried to create static Observer with debounce, but it didn't work since I guess I can't access static properties from non-static method. I'm a bit new to angular and typescript and now I'm lost. Is there a way to create some kind of singleton or static class class with property accessible to all objects in angular?

This is what code looks like right now:

```
export class QueryResultNotificatorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private readonly notificator: NotificationService) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                // all is fine here
            }),
            tap(x => {
                if ((req.method === "PUT" || req.method === "POST" || req.method === "DELETE") &&
                    x instanceof HttpResponse && x.status === 200) {
                        this.notificator.succesfullySaved(); // shows toast
                }
            })
        );
    }
}
```